# String to BigDecimal value

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Can someone help me getting the exact value to `BigDecimal`?

My code is as below,

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         String x="2.7955814565E10";
         BigDecimal y=new BigDecimal(x);
         System.out.println(y.toPlainString());
     }
}
```

My actual value in the DB is **27955814565.0**, a `String`. I read this string from DB and set it in a bean class where the amt field has type string, using the value "2.7955814565E10". When I try to convert this to a `BigDecimal` I get 27955814565 instead of 27955814565.0.

Can someone tell me what is the issue because for rest all fields the logic for converting the string value to BigDecimal is working fine and I want the exact value as in DB?

Comment: Value wise, `27955814565.0` and `27955814565` are equal. The difference is in the representation of the value. You may need to format the output from the `BigDecimal` if there is a standard representation. If you want to display the exact representation as your DB, then you should store the value as a `String`.

Comment: @jai am storing value as string only but the problem is after retrieving the value from db ..am converting to bigdecimal and again storing the value as string.And I have observed that during converting to bigdecimal itself .0 trimmed

Comment: I mean, storing the value in your code as `String` (i.e. there is no more `BigDecimal`). You can still convert it to `BigDecimal` when you need to do any comparison or arithmetic though.

Comment: What is the issue with storing the value without the `.0`? (As @Jai correctly pointed out, it’s the same value, and `BigDecimal` will also accept it next time you retrieve it.) Maybe you should look for a solution somewhere else. See [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Or else [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) may be a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The BigDecimal doesn't infer extra digits in this case.

If the input is

```
String x = "2.79558145650E10"; // note the extra 0
```

you get the expected result.  You can also add the digit as required.

```
String x = "2.7955814565E10";
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(x);
if (y.scale() < 1)
    y = y.setScale(1);
System.out.println(y.toPlainString());
```

prints

```
27955814565.0
```

BTW If your input is

```
String x = "2.7955814565000E10"; // note the extra 000
```

the output is

```
27955814565.000
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, Your String is in scientific notation,
To translate these value into origional BigDecimal or Decimal we need a proper way.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double firstNumber = 12345678;
    double secondNumber = 0.000012345678;
    String firstNumberAsString = String.format ("%.0f", firstNumber);
    String secondNumberAsString = String.format("%.12f",secondNumber);
    System.out.println(firstNumberAsString);
    System.out.println(secondNumberAsString);
}
```

}

output will be:

12345678

0.000012345678

You can use Format method as well on BigDecimal to achieve your goal.

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0000000000");